# When did Batman save a kid from jumping off from roof, just by talking with him for a while?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

I saw a panel once where Batman saves a kid who was going to jump from a roof. He just talks with him for a while, which make the kid change his mind.

Which comic is this from?

Comment: There's an exact match but for Superman: https://imgur.com/gallery/Ijdxh

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Precisely what I was thinking of.

Comment: I see Reed Richards and Superman a couple of times, but no Batman; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TalkingDownTheSuicidal

Comment: https://static2.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111114841/5357740-5357168-bm_4_4.jpg

Comment: I was also thinking Superman, but I thought it was http://comicsalliance.com/files/2012/09/supermanrooftop.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batman debuted in 1939, so I strongly suspect that he has "talked someone down from the ledge," or variations on that theme, on *multiple* occasions over the past **78 years.** But, as I read your description of what you remembered, one particular instance jumped into my mind. I remembered the story title, the fact that it was published in the "Batman" series in the late 1980s, and the fact that it was scripted by Jim Starlin. So it wasn't hard to find the issue number and some scanned images. (My copy must be miles away from where I'm sitting, but it turns out that someone else has already discussed this comic book story in detail [in a blog post](https://ninjadogcorps.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/my-batman-you-should-have-seen-him/).)

Here's the front cover of the comic book in question. I offer it in case it will help you find it in a store, although the artwork doesn't have anything to do with the suicide subplot.

[image]

***Batman #423,*** cover-dated September 1988, written by Jim Starlin.

The story title is: "You Should Have Seen Him." It starts out with some cops sitting in a bar, all of them having recently come off duty after doing a night shift. It turns out that three of these guys each bumped into Batman in the line of duty during the night -- at different times and places -- and each of the three saw a very different side of him, depending upon the nature of the emergency which he was dealing with. We see those experiences as flashbacks narrated by each storyteller.

Here's an excerpt from the blogger's discussion of the first cop's tale about what he saw Batman do. It's followed by a scanned image of some key panels as Batman is trying to drive some sense into the head of a very unhappy African-American lad.

> In the first story, a young, poor, black man named Kenny is about to
>   throw himself off of a bridge, gaining the attention of the police and
>   a crowd of onlookers. He explains that as a junkie, he is incapable of
>   recovering his life from the mess it has become. Arriving on the scene
>   is Batman, whose presence only seems to provoke the man further. After
>   some back and forth, Kenny says, “Listen man, I’m poor, I’m black … I
>   got a jones I can’t shake … got no family, no job … no future … ain’t
>   no better life waiting for me.” The junkie then jumps, and Batman
>   leaps after and catches the man in mid-air while suspending both of
>   them from his Bat-rope.

Then, while they're dangling from the bridge, Batman offers some advice to his captive audience. The blogger quotes the advice in full, and also shows us a scan of a few panels' worth of it.

The full text of Batman's remarks was:

> **BATMAN:** That was real stupid, Kenny. You threw your life away! Wasted
>   it! By all rights, you should be dead now! But you’re not! You got
>   another chance. It’s time to start over, Kenny. Get on a drug rehab
>   program. Clean up your body and your life. Quit looking for excuses to
>   fail! You’ve got as good a shot at life as anyone. **Think about it!**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I think there's at least a fighting chance that this is the story you wanted, although -- as I said before -- Batman has probably talked some other very unhappy youngster out of committing suicide at some other point in his long career, so I can't be sure if this is the same thing you saw before.